# Using slow dns a VPN Over DNS Tunnel android app

Tags: applications, settings, vpn

I'm looking for similar apps that i can use for free, setting dns and start the vpn to get unlimited internet without the silly 25mb of slowdns. thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If looking for a free openVPN app, you can check this [FeatVPN](http://www.featvpn.com/), and get the free openVPN bundles right here: [VPNbook bundles](http://www.vpnbook.com/freevpn).

These bundles have custom DNS therefore can bypass your ISP which may have been slow. Alternatively you can get [DNS Overrider](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mx17.overridedns&hl=en) (if you are rooted)